# want to create modify button in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android development, i want to create a button, but i don't know how i create this button, i searched on 'google' but failed to create.

[image]

I created a button, But don't know i change this to like above image.
here is code:-

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
             <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
           <item><layer-list>
            <item  android:top="5dp"><shape>
                    <corners android:radius="3dp" />

                    <solid android:color="#3366ff" />
                </shape></item>
            <item android:bottom="2dp" >
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#E2E2E2" android:startColor="#3366ff" />

                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#3366ff" />

                    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape></item>
        </layer-list></item>
      </selector>
```

and button is:-

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="@style/btnStyleOrange"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/SyncButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:text="Watch Ad"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

Comment: Please, put the error stack. The link or image you wrote don't work.

Comment: Link is working fine. Button with text "Vendor details".

Comment: You can drag the button in Eclipse IDE and use background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this link it will help you to create custom button.
http://angrytools.com/android/button/

all you have to do is save the button.xml file in your drawable folder and then set your button background as

```
android:background="@drawable/button.xml"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your above btnStyleOrange.xml file in drawable folder and add it  like this

```
 <Button
   android:id="@+id/button2"
 android:background="@drawable/btnStyleOrange" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/SyncButton"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
android:text="Watch Ad"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:textSize="24sp" />
```

Comment: No, My button is working fine, I want to modify my drawable folder xml file, so i make that button which i shows in image.

Answer (score 0):

add to your button

```
android:background="@drawable/btnStyleOrange"
```

Comment: NO, i am doing it with style.xml, So everything is working fine, but i want to create that type of blue button.